# Error in vecseq data, merge (join many-one) data.table r

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have 2 data.tables:

- **train.o** with 160057 rows, column id is unique
- **train.t** with 187105085 rows, column id is not unique, there are 160057 unique id, all in train.o

I want to merge it, to have a single data.table with 187105085 rows.

When I type

```
> setkey(train.o,id)
> setkey(train.t,id)
> trainbig=merge(train.t,train.o)
```

I get

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else
>   as.integer(max(nrow(x),  :   Join results in more than 2^31 rows
>   (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified
>   join. Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the
>   same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j`
>   and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to
>   avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error
>   message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for
>   advice.

What do I wrong?

EDIT:

```
> head(train.o)
 offer       id chain market repeattrips repeater  offerdate category quantity   company
1: 1197502    86252   205     34          16        t 2013-03-27     3203        1 106414464
2: 1208251    86246   205     34           5        t 2013-04-24     2202        1 104460040
3: 1197502 12682470    18     11           0        f 2013-03-28     3203        1 106414464
4: 1197502 12996040    15      9           0        f 2013-03-25     3203        1 106414464
5: 1204821 13089312    15      9           0        f 2013-04-01     5619        1 107717272
6: 1197502 13179265    14      8           0        f 2013-03-29     3203        1 106414464
   offervalue  brand
1:       0.75  13474
2:       2.00   3718
3:       0.75  13474
4:       0.75  13474
5:       1.50 102504
6:       0.75  13474

> head(train.t)
     id chain dept category    company brand       date productsize productmeasure
1 86246   205    7      707 1078778070 12564 2012-03-02          12             OZ
2 86246   205   63     6319  107654575 17876 2012-03-02          64             OZ
3 86246   205   97     9753 1022027929     0 2012-03-02           1             CT
4 86246   205   25     2509  107996777 31373 2012-03-02          16             OZ
5 86246   205   55     5555  107684070 32094 2012-03-02          16             OZ
6 86246   205   97     9753 1021015020     0 2012-03-02           1             CT
  purchasequantity purchaseamount
1                1           7.59
2                1           1.59
3                1           5.99
4                1           1.99
5                2          10.38
6                1           7.80
```

Comment: At least show us the structure, column names of your data sets and also show us that there are no duplicated elements on the column you're joining.

Comment: The data come from [link]http://www.kaggle.com/c/acquire-valued-shoppers-challenge/data

-train.o is merge(trainHistory,offers,by="offer")
-train.t is subset(transactions,id %in% trainHistory$id)

The transactions file can be joined to the history file by (id,chain). But setkey for both id and chain doesn't help.

Comment: I've also edited post to include heads of both data.tables

Comment: what does `sum(!duplicated(train.o$id))` and `sum(!duplicated(train.t$id))` give?

Comment: Both 160057, I wrote it in the beginning.

Comment: Okay one last test before I give up. What does `sum(is.na(match(unique_values_from_train.o, unique_values_train.t)))` give? Just to verify if the keys are identical in both. I'm sorry I don't have the time to download GBs of data from Kaggle. The objective should be to produce a minimal example, but that seems to be not the case here. So, this'll be my last attempt.

Comment: It seems as though you are just running up against the language limits on the integer class.

Comment: If you mean unique values of id in both data.tables it gives 0. I'm wondering if it is not a bug in data.table. When I merge in the same way offers and trainHistory to get train.o it works.

Comment: Especially that plyr's join(train.t,train.o,by="id") succeed.

Comment: Could you tell what's the class of `id` in all these data.tables?

Comment: Could you please try again from the current development version from [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried an unelegant (but effective):

```
trainbig=merge(train.t,train.o, by=.EACHI, all=T)
```

and then manually removing the variables you are not interested in?